# Getting undefined ID for <div> in JSP using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jsp, jakarta-ee, html

I have written jsp code somewhat like this:

```
<%
    out.println("<div id=\""+rs.getString(2)+"\" align=\"center\"  onclick=\"showDialog()\" style=\"float:left;background-color:#b4cde6; height: 150px; width: 200px;margin:20px \">");

            out.println("<p style=\"background-color:#ffffff;width:200px;\">NAME-"
                            + rs2.getString(2) + "</p>");

                    /* out.println("<input type=\"submit\" value=\""
                    + rs.getString(2) + "\" name=\"group\">");
                     */
                    out.println("<a  name=\"class_start\" value=\""
                            + rs.getString(1)
                            + "\"  style=\"background-color:#B4CDE6;width:200px;\" href=\"http://localhost:8080/ClassKarma_1/angular-gauge.jsp\">"+rs.getString(5)+"</a>");
        %>
    </div>
```

Here I am dynamically adding the id for < div> but when I am trying to show a alert with its ID in javascript  like this:

```
function showDialog() {
alert(this.id+" ID");
    };
```

It shows an alert with undefined Id . I am new to this (It may be possible the technique I am using is totally wrong). Please can any one help me solving this?

**UPDATE**

The generated html is like this.I think its perfect.

```
          <div  style="background-color:#fffff;overflow:hidden; height:800px; width: 800px;">
        <div id="1" align="center"  onclick="showDialog()" style="float:left;background-color:#b4cde6; height: 150px; width: 200px;margin:20px "><p style="background-color:#ffffff;width:200px;">NAME-Saurabh</p><a  name="class_start" value="1"  style="background-color:#B4CDE6;width:200px;" href="http://localhost:8080/ClassKarma_1/angular-gauge.jsp">3</a></div>   <div id="2" align="center"  onclick="showDialog()" style="float:left;background-color:#b4cde6; height: 150px; width: 200px;margin:20px "><p style="background-color:#ffffff;width:200px;">NAME-Syed</p><a  name="class_start" value="1"  style="background-color:#B4CDE6;width:200px;" href="http://localhost:8080/ClassKarma_1/angular-gauge.jsp">1</a></div>
```

Comment: IDs cannot have a space in them, would be my first guess.  I would then assume something is wrong with the JSP.  If you can show the generated HTML i'd be of more help.

Comment: I have added the Html Both div have different Ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution:

```
<%
    out.println("<div id=\""+rs.getString(2)+"\" align=\"center\"  onclick=\"showDialog(" + rs.getString(2) + ")\" style=\"float:left;background-color:#b4cde6; height: 150px; width: 200px;margin:20px \">");

        out.println("<p style=\"background-color:#ffffff;width:200px;\">NAME-"
                        + rs2.getString(2) + "</p>");

                /* out.println("<input type=\"submit\" value=\""
                + rs.getString(2) + "\" name=\"group\">");
                 */
                out.println("<a  name=\"class_start\" value=\""
                        + rs.getString(1)
                        + "\"  style=\"background-color:#B4CDE6;width:200px;\" href=\"http://localhost:8080/ClassKarma_1/angular-gauge.jsp\">"+rs.getString(5)+"</a>");
    %>
</div>
```

JS

```
function showDialog(id) {
    alert(id + " ID");
};
```

Explanation:

for the onclick event that was being generated in the backend to be displayed a simple change was made:

Original:

```
onclick=\"showDialog()\"
```

Modified:

```
onclick=\"showDialog(" + rs.getString(2) + ")
```

Because of this modification the function for javascript also had to be modified to accept the parameter...

This can also be done by passing "this" into the onclick function and changing the javascript function to accept the "this" as a parameter.  This would resolve the issue but it would pass the whole div item clicked and not just the ID of the div that was clicked as you specified you wanted.  If you need to change the text of the div clicked or do anything DOM related you should pass "this" if you are using jQuery.

Comment: Providing an explanation about what you changed and why makes your answer even better ;)

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `showDialog` function, `this` refers to `window`, since you are calling the function normally, like `showDialog()`. If you want `this` to refer to the element, you have to use [`.call` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```
onclick=\"showDialog.call(this, event)\"
```

Learn more about `this`:

- [quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html)
- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Alternatively, you can pass the element as argument to the function:

```
onclick=\"showDialog(this)\"
```

and

```
function showDialog(element) {
    alert(element.id);
}
```